# 'Exception from HRESULT: 0X800A01B6' error in PowerShell when trying to enter login information to Facebook

Tags: powershell

I have this code written in PowerShell:

```
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$url = "www.facebook.com/login";

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);

($ie.document.getElementsByName("email") |select -first 1).value = $username;
```

And there is when I get this error message:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At line:1 char:1
+ ($ie.document.getElementsByName("email") |select -first 1).value = $u ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException
```

Any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you done any research on this yourself? I'm not familiar with powershell but the error seems like a syntax error with the first character which is an open parenthesis?

Comment: @owler it's not a syntax error; that `(` is closed right before `.value`. I'm speculating but the `NotSupportedException` leads me to believe that `.value` is not writable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen as IE is still loading the page or parsing DOM. Try waiting for IE not to be busy before accessing page elements. A simple check for IE's [Busy property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752050(v=vs.85).aspx) will do. Like so,

```
$username="myname"
$password="mypass"
$url = "www.facebook.com/login"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)

# Sleep while IE is busy. Check 10 times per second, adjust delay as needed
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

# IE is not busy with document anymore, pass credentials and click the logon    
($ie.document.getElementsByName("email") |select -first 1).value = $username
($ie.document.getElementsByName("pass") |select -first 1).value = $password
($ie.document.getElementsByName("login") |select -first 1).click()
```

Comment: Even if IE is idle, the situation happens. Please refer the ans provided by Wendolin.

Comment: In my case, only way to make this work was to use access those methods from "IHTMLDocument3" as explained below

Answer (score 12):

Workaround
Always use the following methods instead of the native ones:

```
IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName   
IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName
IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID
```

Thanks to Paul Lim [Here](https://paullimblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/28/powershell-exception-0x800a01b6-while-using-getelementsbytagname-getelementsbyname-or-getelementbyid/)

Comment: I'd format code and code related parts and the link, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
$Url = "http://websiteurl"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true; # make to $true to see the result in webpage
$ie.navigate($Url);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 10; }
($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("btnname") | select -first 1).click();
$ie.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. I cant understand  why the getElementsByName is not available from Documents object property

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using

```
do{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}While($ie.Busy -eq $True)
do{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}While($ie.ReadyState -ne 4)
```

Still have chance get Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6 error !

But if you add the code

```
do{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}While((($ie.document.getElementsByName("login")).GetType()) -eq "DBNull")
```

before you using $ie.document.getElementsByName
then the error code 0x800A01B6 will no longer happen

Comment: `do{
    Write-Host 1;
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
} While($ie.Document.getElementByID('table').GetType().Name -ne "__ComObject")`
This fixed it for me, thanks!