# Understanding Powershell HRESULT: 0x800A01B6 Error getElementById

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

For the following question, `$doc` is the `.Document` of a `-ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"`  I'm using Powershell 5.1, Windows 10.

What is the difference between methods:

```
$doc.getElementById("divdetails")
```

and

```
$doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("divdetails")
```

?

The former worked for a day.  The next morning, no change to the script and `.getElementById()` resulted in error: `HRESULT: 0x800A01B6` every time.

The solution on [this page](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2016/05/03/powershell-exception-0x800a01b6-while-using-getelementsbytagname-getelementsbyname) says to always use the latter version `$doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById()` instead.  Indeed, that fixes it.  Why?

What's the difference?

Comment: One possible track here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823005/exception-from-hresult-0x800a01b6-error-in-powershell-when-trying-to-enter-lo

Comment: Interesting idea.  I changed it back to original code (without the `IHTMLDocument3_`) and presently it's not failing whereby I can test.  I do have `while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }` in the code already which should be requiring IE to fully load.