# bypass IE not support issue

Tags: html, powershell, autologin

I've read through so many threads for this and haven't found a good solution for my issue. I'm writing a script to direct to a page, bypass an SSL certification error and then auto login. Everything works fine up until inputting any login information. From the thread I've read, it could be due to an IE error with HTML5 so I'm wondering if there is a way around the issue or how would I rewrite this script to pull in Chrome instead?

Code:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome Kat to SO, 

So quick rule of thumb, Do not post code as a picture or link. Please post code in the post as well as error. The reason is because if that image is taken offline one day and then this post wont make any sense, Also there is no way for me to copy and paste the code to try and see whats wrong. Its ok not to format correctly at first but there are plenty of people here that will fix your formating and grammar issues while you get the hang of it :)

Comment: Also another reason Posting code as a image is bad....No way for me to copy and paste it and work with it myself. Not many people will rewrite all ur code from a image

Comment: If by any chance you do those changes i sent above please comment on here using @arcset so i can come back and look at it :)

Comment: See if the comments in this older SO post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823005/exception-from-hresult-0x800a01b6-error-in-powershell-when-trying-to-enter-lo

Comment: In my tests I've noticed that IE can take a moment to become busy after Navigate, and may skip over the while loop as a result. So it's better to use do..while instead for line 6: `do {sleep -m 100} while ($ie.Busy) #sometimes IE takes a moment to get busy` - Edit: looks like you already have the fix on line 14. 
Good luck!