# Website Login Automation and Output STatus

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate a task to login and verify or not login is success in a nutshell I am able to create.

```
$username = "XXXX"
$password = "XXXXXXXX"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://com/login")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("user_email").value= "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("user_password").value = "$password"
$ie.document.getElementById("Loginform").submit()
start-sleep 20
$ie.Document.body
```

Its throwing error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
+ $ie.document.getElementById("user_email").value= "$username"
At line:8 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementById("user_password").value = "$password"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At line:9 char:1
```

i can confirm that the HTML id for the login box is user_email and user_password

Comment: hi! have you tried using `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("user_email")` like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823005/exception-from-hresult-0x800a01b6-error-in-powershell-when-trying-to-enter-lo#37826851

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Exception from HRESULT: 0X800A01B6' error in PowerShell when trying to enter login information to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823005/exception-from-hresult-0x800a01b6-error-in-powershell-when-trying-to-enter-lo)